# Changing file permissions in SD card with my phone

Tags: permissions, sd-card

I have arch linux on a SD card and I need to change a configuration file. I can only do it with my phone (Android 6.0 cyanogenmod based). Problem is that the file manager (I'm using cyanogenmod default file manager but I tried ES file manager too) tells me I don't have permission to do it even having my phone rooted and having granted it superuser powers. I suspect it's an SD card thing, maybe it's Android that respects the fact that the file is a system file which was created in another environment. What can I try to do? I chose to post here instead on android network because I thought the permission thing was more relevant to this section

Comment: Since Android 5.x you can no longer write to the SD card directly, "for security reasons". As you can imagine, various workarounds are possible for rooted systems, but they are device-dependent.

Comment: Ahh that sucks... Hopefully I'll find a workaround. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Android. Android is not a Unix system, even if it uses a Linux kernel. Privileges, in particular, are managed very differently from a Linux-based Unix system. You can ask Android questions on [android.se].